# How to match two strings with integers greater than zero using regex?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a simple regex to match this:

```
int.int"
```

where the integer is greater then `0`.

matches:

```
1.1"
1.5"
5.1"
40.30"
1.29"
```

mismatches:

```
1.1
0.4"
4.0"
0.30"
39.0"
```

Comment: This kind of regex is not really hard to write, did you try by yourself before asking ?

Comment: Yes i tried, but i asked my question 'to simple' I don't know much about regex, and there is always something wrong with the regex's that i tried ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*"$
```

[Rubular Link](http://www.rubular.com/r/ks9flAGPpb)

```
^     : Start anchor
[1-9] : Non zero digit
[0-9]*: Zero or more of any digit 0-9
\.    : A literal period
"     : A literal "
$     : End anchor
```

The anchors are essential. Without them you'll match any string that has the pattern you want **anywhere**, say `foo11.22bar`. With the anchors the *regex will try to match the entire string not just any proper subset of it*.

`.` is a regex meta character which matches any character (other than newline).
To match a literal `.` you need to escape it as `\.`.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, but i asked my question wrong :( i meant any integer greater than zero, and not only 1 to 9  (stupid me) see for the update. thanks, Bruno.

Comment: Just add `\d*` after each `[1-9]`.

Answer (score 3):

Is this for .NET?

```
[1-9]\.[1-9]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's for replacing it in msbuild with fileupdate. And i asked my question to simple. I meant any integer greater than zero and not only 1-9. See for the update. Thanks, Bruno.

Answer (score 0):

I've founded this "myself":

```
[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*"
```

Of course with the initial help of the people who reacted. (and a fresh head in the morning :-) )

As Alan Moore commented in coaddict answer, you can also use:

```
[1-9]\d*\.[1-9]\d*"
```

Thanks for all who helped.

Bruno

Comment: I'm sure @codaddict would have come up with the same answer, once you updated the question.  I only added that comment to get you going until he looks in next and updates the answer, expecting you to accept the answer.