# Regex expression to match equal or greater than 1, by increments of .5

Tags: regex

Upon several attempts and research I can't find the correct solution for this problem:

Need to match equal or greater than 1;
And increments of .5 are also valid;
only one decimal place.

In essence I need to capture 1 1.5 2 2.5 and so on.

Looking around, found the following help:
[perl regex to find any number that is a multiple of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557754/perl-regex-to-find-any-number-that-is-a-multiple-of-5)

[Regex greater than zero with 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609714/regex-greater-than-zero-with-2-decimal-places)

[How to match two strings with integers greater than zero using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144269/how-to-match-two-strings-with-integers-greater-than-zero-using-regex)

I have tried:

```
(?!\d[0.5])\d+|\.|\d*[05]\d{1}$
```

With no success.

Can you help please?

Comment: Try `[1-9]\d*(\.5)?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[1-9]\d*(?:\.[05])?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mV3wC2/1)

**Breakup:**

```
^        # Start of input
[1-9]    # match digit 1 to 9
\d*      # match 0 or more of any digits
(?:      # start of non-capturing group
   \.    # match a decimal
   [05]  # followed by digit 0 or 5
)?       # end non-capturing group. (? makes this group optional)
$        # End of input
```

Comment: I'm happy, I was close

Comment: Oh yes, you were totally on the money other than couple of minor things.